# How to stop phpstorm highlights?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I am currently faced with the following issue.

http://imgkk.com/i/60pp.png

Not sure why this is happening however it is most likely due to PHPStorm not recognising Laravel.

Any ideas how to remove the highlighting as it is quite of putting.

Comment: Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> {PICK A CATEGORY} and edit... next time search before asking.

Answer (score 2):

PHPStorm is correctly highlighting that, it's invalid syntax.

You want `return view('pages.about');`, not `return view.pages.about';`

Comment: I am aware of the error however I would like to remove highlighting all together. I dont mind underlines but the highlights seem to irritate me too much. This for example http://imgkk.com/i/vorb.png

Answer (score 1):

You can add barryhd's ide helper to get correct highlighting and class recognition in phpstorm, though your syntax actually really is wrong.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper